# erlang-shell mode in Emacs doesn't show the error_logger error

Tags: shell, logging, emacs, erlang

I like Emacs and Erlang too; I have set-up the `erlang-mode` and `distel` properly.

In my project，when dealing with the log，it doesn't show the

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 15-Sep-2012::14:09:30 ===
```

in the erlang-shell.

However in Windows it works.
but, I like to develop on Ubuntu. Could anyone give me some advice on how to get it to work？

Comment: Did you try to log something on Linux using the Erlang shell?

Comment: [
  {sasl, [   
     {sasl_error_logger, false},    
     {errlog_type, error},   
     {error_logger_mf_dir, "./logs"},     %% dirs
     {error_logger_mf_maxbytes, 1048760}, %% 10M per log file.   
     {error_logger_mf_maxfiles, 10}       %% maxinum number of 10
     ]
   }
]
this is my sasl config

Comment: i can only get the log in my log file .
In emacs using the erlang-shell-mode , when input the error_logger:error_msg("some_msg"). 
the erlang-shell can output someting like 
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1> error_logger:error_msg("sdfsdf").
ok
2> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Sep-2012::12:05:50 ===
sdfsdf2> 
but in my application  just output ok:
(algking@127.0.0.1)11> error_logger:error_msg("sdfsdf").
ok

Answer (score 0):

`{sasl_error_logger, false}` is your problem.  That tells your Erlang node to turn off logging to the terminal and to plain text files.  According to [the manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sasl_app.html), you can set it to either `tty` or `{file, "mylog.txt"}` to get log output.

You also have this in your config, though:

```
{error_logger_mf_dir, "./logs"}, %% dirs
{error_logger_mf_maxbytes, 1048760}, %% 10M per log file.
{error_logger_mf_maxfiles, 10}
```

That makes your Erlang node save error messages in a binary format in multiple files (hence `mf`) in `./logs`.  You can use [the report browser](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/sasl/error_logging.html#id60581) (section 2.5, "Report Browser") to access them.

Comment: I have tried tty ,but it still doesn't work ,the problem is the same config and the same code works  in  the windows

Comment: Hm, apart from that, the problem might be that sasl isn't started.  Try `application:start(sasl)`.

Comment: I'm sure the sasl is started:                      application:start(sasl).
{error,{already_started,sasl}}. I guess,maybe is some problem in the emacs ? or my erlang-shell-mode using in the emacs?